# Chaining observable results

Tags: angular, typescript, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to fetch the customerID from the angular class "UserFacade" and then
using the retrieved customerID to retrieve the points for this customer using a http client GET call
to a REST endpoint.

The approach I am using is creating 2 variables user$ and point$ which must be initialized
correctly which will guarantee me that the points are received correctly. Is there a
better way implement this logic for example not using these two variables user$ and point$ and directly retrieve them via let's say function `getPts():number`?

The HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <ng-container *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
    <ng-container *ngIf="point$ | async as point">
         <p>  {{getCustomerPoints()}}  </p> 
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>

</div>
```

This is where main logic resides:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService, CmsComponent, User, UserIdService, } from '@spartacus/core';
import { CmsComponentData } from '@spartacus/storefront';
import { UserAccountFacade } from '@spartacus/user/account/root';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { PointsRetrievalService } from '../points-retrieval.service';
import { FOOTER_VALUE, HEADER_VALUE } from './component-labels';


export interface CustomerPoints {
  points: number;
}


export interface CmsSlpCustomUserPointsComponent4 extends CmsComponent {
  title: string;
  headerText: string;
  footerText: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-userpoints',
  templateUrl: './userpoints.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userpoints.component.scss']
})
export class UserpointsComponent implements OnInit {
  public point$!: Observable<CustomerPoints>;
  user$: Observable<User | undefined> | undefined;
  data$: Observable<CmsSlpCustomUserPointsComponent4> = this.component.data$;
  private customerPointsRetrieved = 0
  constructor(
    public component: CmsComponentData<CmsSlpCustomUserPointsComponent4>, private pointsRetrievalService: PointsRetrievalService,
    protected auth: AuthService,
    protected userAccount: UserAccountFacade,
    protected userIdService: UserIdService,
  ) {}


  ngOnInit() : void {
    this.user$ = this.auth.isUserLoggedIn().pipe(
      switchMap(isUserLoggedIn => {
        if (isUserLoggedIn) {
     
          this.userAccount.get().subscribe(
            (user) =>
            {
              if(user && user?.customerId)
              {
                this.point$ = this.pointsRetrievalService.getPointsForCustomerId(user?.customerId) 
                this.point$.subscribe(
                  (userPoints) =>
                  {
                    console.log("New points:" +userPoints.points)
                    console.log(userPoints.points)
                    this.customerPointsRetrieved = userPoints.points
                  }
                )
              }
            }
          )
      
          return this.userAccount.get();  
        } else {
          return of(undefined);
        }
      })
    );

  }



getCustomerPoints()
{
  return this.customerPointsRetrieved;
}

}
```

Service retrieving the points via http:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserAccountFacade } from '@spartacus/user/account/root';
import { BASE_SITE_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, ELECTRONICS_SITE, HTTP_JSON_HEADERS, REST_URL } from './userpoints/rest-connection-constants';
import { CustomerPoints } from './userpoints/customer-points-interfaces';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PointsRetrievalService{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    protected userAccount: UserAccountFacade) {

  }

  getPointsForCustomerId(userID: string): Observable<CustomerPoints>
   {
    {
      console.log("User id received:" + userID)
      const url = `${REST_URL}${userID}`;
      //const url = this.mainRestUrl + this.userIdUsed + this.fieldParams;
      console.log(url);

      let params = new HttpParams().set(CUSTOMER_ID, userID).set(BASE_SITE_ID, ELECTRONICS_SITE);

      const options = { params: params, headers: HTTP_JSON_HEADERS }

      return this.http.get<CustomerPoints>(url, options);
    }

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of `user$` and `point$` streams.

Also, the logic in ngOnInit seems a bit too complicated (usually nested subscribes are not a good pattern).

I've made some changes but I can't really test anything, so if you have issues let me know. Maybe you can adapt it to work.

```js
import {
    Observable,
    of,
    Subject,
} from 'rxjs';
import {
    switchMap,
    takeUntil,
    tap,
} from 'rxjs/operators';

import {
    Component,
    OnDestroy,
    OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    AuthService,
    CmsComponent,
    UserIdService,
} from '@spartacus/core';
import { CmsComponentData } from '@spartacus/storefront';
import { UserAccountFacade } from '@spartacus/user/account/root';

import { PointsRetrievalService } from '../points-retrieval.service';

export interface CustomerPoints {
    points: number;
}


export interface CmsSlpCustomUserPointsComponent4 extends CmsComponent {
    title: string;
    headerText: string;
    footerText: string;
}

const customerPointsKey = 'CUSTOMER_POINTS_KEY';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-userpoints',
    templateUrl: './userpoints.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./userpoints.component.scss']
})
export class UserpointsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    data$: Observable<CmsSlpCustomUserPointsComponent4> = this.component.data$;
    private customerPointsRetrieved = localStorage.getItem(customerPointsKey) ?? 0;
    private _destroyed$ = new Subject<void>();
    constructor(
        public component: CmsComponentData<CmsSlpCustomUserPointsComponent4>, private pointsRetrievalService: PointsRetrievalService,
        protected auth: AuthService,
        protected userAccount: UserAccountFacade,
        protected userIdService: UserIdService,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.auth.isUserLoggedIn().pipe(
            switchMap(isUserLoggedIn => {
                if (isUserLoggedIn) {
                    return this.userAccount.get().pipe(
                        switchMap(user => {
                            if (user && user?.customerId) {
                                return this.pointsRetrievalService.getPointsForCustomerId(user.customerId).pipe(
                                    tap(userPoints => {
                                        console.log("New points:" userPoints.points)
                                        console.log(userPoints.points)
                                        this.customerPointsRetrieved = userPoints.points;
                                        localStorage.setItem(customerPointsKey, userPoints.points);
                                    })
                                )
                            }

                            return of(undefined);
                        })
                    )
                }

                return of(undefined);
            }),
            takeUntil(this._destroyed$),
        ).subscribe();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._destroyed$.next();
    }

    getCustomerPoints() {
        return this.customerPointsRetrieved;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>{{getCustomerPoints()}}</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: I will try it out and share the result

Comment: It works, just not sure why only in the case when I hit F5 on the page the component renders the default value which is 0 from ```private customerPointsRetrieved = 0``` instead of using the one being set

Comment: Well it's because it waits for the network requests to be finished. You can store it on localStorage after the request has been made, and read it from there in the service if you have it. If you don't, default to 0.

Comment: also, you can move the logic from ngOnInit in the constructor, so it starts faster ! :D

Comment: Can you show how this can be done?

Comment: yep, I've changed the code (please look there).

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the point of `pipe`, you can pass any number of arguments, each is a step in the pipeline. The result of a previous step is passed to the next step. You don't subscribe inside the pipeline, you create the pipeline and then subscribe.

So an observable that returns the user points look like this:

```js
  userPoints$: Observable<Points[] | undefined> = this.auth
    .isUserLoggedIn()
    .pipe(
      switchMap((isUserLoggedIn) =>
        isUserLoggedIn ? this.userAccount.get() : of(undefined)
      ),
      switchMap((user: User | undefined) => {
        if (!user || !user.customerId) return of(undefined);
        return this.pointsRetrievalService.getPointsForCustomerId(
          user.customerId
        );
      }),
      map((userPoints: UserPoints | undefined) => userPoints?.points)
    );
```

Note: `switchMap` and `mergeMap` will pass the *result* of the returned observable to the next step, while `map` will just pass the return value. The result of the final step is what ultimately gets returned.

You can add steps by calling pipe on another observable as well. So if you want a separate observable to return just the user you can do this:

```js
  user$: Observable<User | undefined> = this.auth
    .isUserLoggedIn()
    .pipe(
      switchMap((isUserLoggedIn) =>
        isUserLoggedIn ? this.userAccount.get() : of(undefined)
      )
    );

  userPoints$: Observable<Points[] | undefined> = this.user$.pipe(
    switchMap((user: User | undefined) => {
      if (!user || !user.customerId) return of(undefined);
      return this.pointsRetrievalService.getPointsForCustomerId(
        user.customerId
      );
    }),
    map((userPoints: UserPoints | undefined) => userPoints?.points)
  );
```

You can initialize these outside of any function, nothing will be executed until you subscribe.

You can subscribe to the new observables manually, or you can use the `async` pipe in html to automatically subscribe / unsubscribe and inject the data into your view.

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Requests just user
    this.user$.subscribe((user) => {
      console.log(user);
    });

    // Requests user and then user points
    this.userPoints$.subscribe((points) => {
      console.log('New points:' + points);
      this.customerPointsRetrieved = points;
    });
  }
```

OR

```html
<h1>User</h1>
<pre>{{ user$ | async | json }}</pre>
<h1>User Points</h1>
<pre>{{ userPoints$ | async | json }}</pre>
```

Notice how `|` is also a `pipe` operator, ie. the result of the previous step is passed to the next.

Just keep in mind every instance of `userPoints$ | async` in html will be a separate request, you can create a template variable if it appears more than once in the view.

---

Also worth mentioning the `async` `await` variant to request the data once instead of subscribing.

```js
  async ngOnInit(): void {
    const user = await firstValueFrom(this.user$);
    const userPoints = await firstValueFrom(this.userPoints$);
    console.log(user, userPoints);
  }
```